# php parse error, str_replace values in array

Tags: php, function, str-replace

I'm trying to make a cool php function to replace stuff but I get parse error for not obvious reason. Am I missing something ?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$array_pairs  = array( '{{simple}}' => 'simple_value', '{{organization}}' => 'Apple Inc');


function the_replace($aray_pairs,  $content){
foreach($aray_pairs as $a => $b)
{
$content = str_replace($a, $b, $content);

 return $content;
}


$invoice = '{{organization}} is a {{simple}}';

$invoice = replace_values($array_pairs, $invoice);
echo $invoice;
```

Comment: Why make a loop?  `$content = str_replace(array_keys($pairs), array_values($pairs), $content);`  str_replace can take an array for search and an array for replace.

Comment: @GigaWatt didn't know that (array_keys, array_values) ! thanks a lot ! I basically tried to make myself a such function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing }
Function name mismatch too

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$array_pairs  = array( '{{simple}}' => 'simple_value', '{{organization}}' => 'Apple Inc');


function replace_values($aray_pairs,  $content){ // function names didn't match too.
   foreach($aray_pairs as $a => $b)
   {
       $content = str_replace($a, $b, $content);

   }
   return $content;

} // here

$invoice = '{{organization}} is a {{simple}}';

$invoice = replace_values($array_pairs, $invoice);
echo $invoice;
```

Comment: thanks, indeed I missed that. Apart of this I get as output {{organization}} is a simple_value instead of expected Apple inc is a simple_value. Any idea how can I fix it ?

Comment: I've just updated my code for you.
You was using `return` within your foreach, so it was returning your content on the first iteration, so it wasn't getting to your second array key (organisation)

Comment: However, you can pass arrays to `str_replace()`, it doesn't have to be a string.